# How do I pin the search button where it is?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see from below link, the search button is expanding with the input are simultaneously. When you click the icon, it is moving too.

[Code](https://codepen.io/xdreva/pen/ZEjOjOd)

```js
const search = document.querySelector('.search')
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
const input = document.querySelector('.input')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  search.classList.toggle('active')
  input.focus()
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #7d5fff, #7158e2);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.search .input {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.btn:focus,
.input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.search.active .input {
  width: 200px;
}

.search.active .btn {
  transform: translateX(198px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Hidden Search</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="search">
    <label>
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Search..." />
      </label>
    <button class="btn">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </button>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

But I want to pin the search button to the right and only expand the input area to the left. I tried `position:fixed` property but it didin't work. Can you help me to handle it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't want to translate the button with the magnifying glass icon at all. However, you have a `translateX` css-property on it which will move it 198px to the right (the positive X-direction).

I would instead animate only the input element with the following modifications to your css classes:

```css
.search .input {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 50px;

    /* Hide the input element by default by making it 0 width */
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    width: 0;
    /* Animate both the width and left properties on css property change */
    transition: width 0.3s ease, left 0.3s ease;
    left: 0;
}

.search.active .input {
    /* Set width and position when this class is active */
    width: 200px;
    left: -200px;
    padding: 15px;
}

/* Remove any transforms for the search button */
/* .search.active .btn {
  transform: translateX(198px);
} */
```